# How do I say: I am on parental leave

Tags: translation

Something like?

今育児休業(いくじきゅうぎょう)です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can say

> 今、[育児休業中]{いくじきゅうぎょうちゅう} / [育児休暇中]{いくじきゅうかちゅう}です。
>   今、[育休]{いくきゅう}で休んでます。

for "I'm on paternal leave" (In Japan, normally starting 8 weeks after the birth of the child and ending by the time when the child turns one year old... I think), and

> 今、[産休中]{さんきゅうちゅう}です。
>   今、産休で休んでます。

for "I'm on maternity leave" (In Japan, normally for 6 weeks before and 8 weeks after the birth of the child... I think).

Answer (score 0):

育児休業 is the right word.

If you are the woman giving birth, you could also use 産休.

Comment: I presume the OP didn't guess the word 育児休業 and knew it to be the right word, but isn't sure **how to use it**. A priori, there might be many options, the OP suggested 育児休業です; 育児休業を取っています, 育児休業中です, 育児休業をしています, etc., might be other options. As it stands, I don't think the answer is of much practical value.

Comment: Ok, do i just put です after? Or する?

Comment: I am a man also, if that makes a difference?

Comment: 父親の育児休業 is a valid expression, but if you, a male, are talking to someone, then saying you are "on parental leave" is probably understood to mean "on paternity leave" and not "on maternity leave".